# Identify a Sonic game which featured Silver in a dystopian future

Tags: story-identification, video-games, sonic-the-hedgehog

I remember playing a Sonic game in which Silver was there, but in a dystopian future. Here are the details I can recall:

- Almost all Sonic characters were there including Silver.
- Time travel was part of the main story. Chaos Emeralds and some Eggman’s tech were used for time travel.
- I remember the stage which featured Silver in high details. It was a dystopian city of the future. The city was engulfed in fire, possibly in the aftermath of nuclear war.

Can you please identify this game and the mentioned stage featuring Silver and dystopian city?

Comment: Sounds like Sonic '06.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pretty sure this is [Sonic '06](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonic_the_Hedgehog_(2006_video_game)) (PS3, Xbox 360). Of all the Sonic games I remember, it's the only one where you play as Silver. Here's a description of that part:

> Silver is from about 200 years after when Sonic appears in this game. His
> world - the future - is devastated and torn apart. This is due to to the fire
> all around them, which is based in a creature called Iblis (also known as the
> Flames of Disaster). With enough struggle, Silver can use his telekinetic
> powers to subdue any of Iblis's outbreaks and destroy him, but Iblis seems to
> be immortal as he always eventually rises from his ashes. The story starts
> with a cinematic. Silver is flying around a completely devastated city
> (formerly Soleanna, now known as "Crisis City") and explaining some of what
> was mentioned above. Blaze then jumps into view and tells Silver that Iblis
> has appeared again. They rush off-camera to quell the threat.
> — [Silver Episode Walkthrough
> by CAVX](https://www.supercheats.com/xbox360/walkthroughs/sonicthehedgehog-walkthrough05.txt)

You can also play as Shadow and also (obviously) Sonic. Many other characters showed up as NPCs (see [cast](https://sega.fandom.com/wiki/Sonic_the_Hedgehog_(2006))). Naturally, as Silver and Blaze are from the future, time travel was an element.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It meant a lot to me. I have added the YouTube video.